# Specifying a meta description for each mobile page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, meta-tags

In jQuery Mobile, we can use the "data-title" attribute to specify a page title for each individual page within a multi-page HTML document, like...

```
<section id="home" data-role="page" data-title="Home Page Title">
```

Which of course makes a lot of sense, because there may be several individual mobile pages contained within a single HTML document, so it's good to be able to specify a unique page title for each one, from an SEO perspective.

But what if we also want to specify a META description for each individual mobile page (in a multi-page document). Is this possible? Or are we stuck using the single META description in the head section of the document? (which would obviously be less than ideal from a SEO perspective).

I've been researching this topic online for the past hour, but surprisingly have yet to find any info on it.

Anyone have the scoop on this?